# Can someone break down a PIVOT query for me please?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to pivot this data so the output can count how many people are in each age band...

Below is what I have done, but I don't even think I'm close....

I am using SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT     [OA_Code], Dominant_F_Age, Age_F_90plus, Age_F_85_89, Age_F_80_84, Age_F_75_79, Age_F_70_74, Age_F_65_69, Age_F_60_64, 
                      Age_F_55_59, Age_F_50_54, Age_F_45_49, Age_F_40_44, Age_F_35_39, Age_F_30_34, Age_F_25_29, Age_F_20_24, Age_F_15_19, Age_F_10_14, Age_F_5_9, 
                      Age_F_0_4, Age_2001_F
FROM         cen.AgeByGenderOA
PIVOT (
    f_Age_data
    for [F_Age_Data] in (Age_F_90plus, Age_F_85_89, Age_F_80_84, Age_F_75_79, Age_F_70_74, Age_F_65_69, Age_F_60_64, 
                      Age_F_55_59, Age_F_50_54, Age_F_45_49, Age_F_40_44, Age_F_35_39, Age_F_30_34, Age_F_25_29, Age_F_20_24, Age_F_15_19, Age_F_10_14, Age_F_5_9), 
                      Age_F_0_4)
```

My table looks like so:

```
CREATE TABLE AgeByGenderOA(
            [OA_Code] AS VARCHAR(50),
            [Age_M_0_4] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_5_9] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_10_14] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_15_19] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_20_24] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_25_29] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_30_34] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_35_39] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_40_44] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_45_49] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_50_54] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_55_59] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_60_64] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_65_69] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_70_74] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_75_79] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_80_84] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_85_89] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_M_90plus] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Dominant_M_Age] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_2001_F] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_0_4] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_5_9] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_10_14] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_15_19] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_20_24] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_25_29] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_30_34] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_35_39] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_40_44] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_45_49] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_50_54] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_55_59] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_60_64] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_65_69] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_70_74] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_75_79] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_80_84] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_85_89] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Age_F_90plus] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Dominant_F_Age] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [MAPINFO_ID] [varchar](50) NULL)
```

As you can see it's a huge table. The "Age_M_0_4" columns are populated with numbers.

I would like my output to read

```
OA_Code, Age, countOfAge
123456, Age_0_4, 26
123456, Age_5_9, 24
789456, Age_0_4, 10
789456, Age_5_9, 12
```

This would be inclusive of male and female ages.

Anyone fancy taking a crack at this one?

Finally: The data contained in the "Age_M_" Columns is all numbers counts. 50, 40, 2, 0 etc...

Comment: You've made it difficult for yourself by having such a heavily denormalized table. You really need a table that is just 3 columns `OA_Code`, `Age` (or maybe `age_range` where you link to another table defining your ranges but preferably you would store actual data in your table and not summarized data) and finally a `gender` column. Then all your queries become a lot easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not want a PIVOT, you need to UNPIVOT the data. Since you are using SQL Server 2008+,  you can use `CROSS APPLY` with a `VALUES` clause.  The code will be similar to this:

```
select t.OA_Code,
  c.age,
  sum(cast(c.value as int)) countOfAge
from AgeByGenderOA t
cross apply
(
  values 
    ('Age_0_4', Age_M_0_4),
    ('Age_5_9', Age_M_5_9),
    ('Age_10_14', Age_M_10_14),
    ('Age_15_19', Age_M_15_19) ... add the other columns here
) c (age, value)
group by t.OA_Code, c.age
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ded85/2)

Edit, If you want both Male/Female columns you will include ALL of the columns in the values clause, but give them the same age range value:

```
select t.OA_Code,
  c.age,
  sum(cast(c.value as int)) countOfAge
from AgeByGenderOA t
cross apply
(
  values 
    ('Age_0_4', Age_M_0_4),
    ('Age_5_9', Age_M_5_9),
    ('Age_10_14', Age_M_10_14),
    ('Age_15_19', Age_M_15_19),
    ('Age_0_4', Age_F_0_4),
    ('Age_5_9', Age_F_5_9),
    ('Age_10_14', Age_F_10_14),
    ('Age_15_19', Age_F_15_19)
) c (age, value)
group by t.OA_Code, c.age;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/343f2/2)

Comment: I don't think this is correct. "Age" in my output example should be generated by the script. Perhaps my provided information wasn't good enough. I will try to make it more clear.

Comment: @Waller Can you provide some sample data? Or edit the SQL Fiddle with some of your actual data?  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ded85/2

Comment: @Waller What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: I've edited my orig submission. It still may be slightly unclear, but what I'm hoping to achieve is group the "M" and "F" ages together, and get a sum( of the numbers held in these age columns.

Comment: @Waller That is correct, you will have to expand the `VALUES` clause to include all of the columns.  I didn't include all of the columns in my answer, since you have about 50 of them.